# How do I convert a string, which is the result from an input function, into a variable?

Tags: python

In python, I am trying to create a simple directory of service providers. For example, one may enter "Plumbers" and get the list of Plumbers servicing one's home area. Below is the sample code.  The expectation was that this code would return the list of names in the dictionary called Plumbers when one enters Plumbers as an input using the code below. However, instead of returning the Plumber Names and Phone numbers (the keys & values in the dictionary), the code below returns the term "Plumbers" only as an put of print(y). I believe this may be due to the fact that the Input function returns strings only and print(y) is not taking y as equal to the variable Plumbers but instead its treating Plumbers as a string. Running the code will probably illustrate easily what I have stated above in case it is not very clear.  My question is how can I get the input function to return the variable Plumbers instead of a string Plumbers? Or is there a better way to do this? Thank you

```py
    Plumbers = {"Plumber 1 Name": "Phone number", "Plumber 2 Name": "Phone 
    number"}
    Electricians = {"Electrician 1 Name" : "Phone number", "Electrician 2 Name" : 
    "Phone number"}

    y = input("Hi, What kind of service do you require? Please type Plumbers or 
    Electricians?")

    print(y)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That is NOT the right way to do it.  Instead create a `Contractors` dictionary that has two elements, `"Plumbers"` and `"Electricians"`.  Now your selection is easy.

Comment: `y` is a name which refers to the string returned from `input()`; you can then use that string for things like comparison `if y.lower().startswith("plumber"): ...`

Comment: The nominal answer to your question is `locals()[y]`, but that **is not the correct Pythonic way to solve the problem**. Tim Roberts has the right idea.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. Very helpful. @TimRoberts: I wanted to clarify some jargon. My understanding is a dictionary contains a key: value pair and the two together are referred to as "items". What is an "element" meant to indicate? Is it referring to a key:value pair? Thank you

Comment: "Element" is just my imprecise way of referring to a key/value pair.

Comment: Got it. Tried both the methods recommended and they work. Thanks all!